# Как длинную строку больше чем из 16 символов, преобразовать в число?

Tags: javascript, длинная-арифметика

```js
let str = "5555555555555555555"

console.log(Number(str)) // 5555555555555555000
```

Хотелось бы увидеть 5555555555555555555

Comment: Зачем? ......И где именно увидеть?

Comment: Это невозможно, у чисел, которые используются в javascript, не хватает точности для этого

Comment: Если точнее, с недавних пор в javascript появился [BigInt](https://learn.javascript.ru/bigint), но не уверен, что это то, что вам нужно

Comment: Увидеть, хотя бы в консоли

Comment: Ну сделайте просто `console.log(str)` зачем для этого в число преобразовывать)

Comment: я так и делаю=)
, но потом мне нужно это число TypeScript, показать c типом  :number

Comment: `console.log(BigInt(str))`

Comment: Type 'bigint' is not assignable to type 'number'

Comment: Перевести его в number невозможно, потому что у типа number недостаточно точности

Comment: спасибо, за BigInt,
и console.log() =)

Comment: > мне нужно это число TypeScript, показать c типом :number... попробуй сначала перекинуть переменную как есть строкой в TS, а уже там конвертировать строку в число. может в TS int повместительнее. я конечно мало что знаю про TS, но он вроде тем и славится что с типизацией в нём знатно поработали.

Comment: @puffleeck, TS никак не виляет на выходной результат, он не выполняется в реальном времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что тип Number не может содержать числа больше, чем 9007199254740991 или меньше, чем -9007199254740991
Используйте специальный числовой тип **BigInt**, для работы с целыми числами произвольной длины

```js
str = "5555555555555555555";
console.log(BigInt(str));
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E).

Comment: Содержать он может, но не точно.